# JavaScript - Convert dates and times (Chart.js and Moment.js)

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, chart.js

**If** you have a better solution (perhaps a D3 solution for this problem): your answer will be appreciated!

I'm new to Chart.js and despite reading the docs of both Chart.js and Moment.js over and over again, I don't seem to possess the skills needed to create the chart I'd like to create.

That said, I have two arrays: one for the `y-axis` and one for the `x-axis`.

You can review, edit, fork and all that **[here on codepen](https://codepen.io/DerkJanS/pen/xrzJvg)**.

It looks like this:

[image]

Now this looks fine, but like I said, I don't seem to possess the `Moment.js` skills to convert those hundreths of a second to a good looking: **`2:31.70`**`(mm:ss:SS)` or **`23.76`**`(ss:SS)` or **`1:58.43.20`**`(HH:mm:ss:SS)`.

Next to the time in hundreths being coverted to a normal time, readable for humans. The date is not quite good looking as well. I'd like to be able to convert this date to a local language and custom format. You may paste your codepen link in your answer. Or if you have any other good examples, that's highly appreciated as well!

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="auto" height="100"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        labels: [
            // x-axis array containing dates as String in YYYY-MM-DD format
            // e.g. 2009-04-11 (April 11, 2009)
        ],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "time",
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                borderColor: "#0088d4",
                data: [
                    // y-axis array containing times as int in one hundredth of a second
                    // e.g.: 15170 (2 minutes, 31 seconds and 70 hundreth of a second)
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        elements: {
            line: {
                tension: 0
            }
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [
                {
                    ticks: {
                        stepSize: 1,
                        callback: function(tickValue, index, ticks) {
                            if (!(index % parseInt(ticks.length / 5))) {
                                return tickValue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What does your values represent? E.g. How `15170` should look like?

Comment: It's in hundredths of a second. So 6000 should say: 1:00.00. So 15170 should say 2:31.70

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) and use [moment-duration-format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) plug-in.

Since your input is an amount of seconds you can use [`moment.duration`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/):

> Moment.js also has duration objects. Where a moment is defined as single points in time, durations are defined as a length of time.

You can create a duration for your value using [`moment.duration(tickValue/100, 'seconds')`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/). Then you can use [moment-duration-format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) to transform 60 seconds to a string like `01:00.00`

> This is a plugin to the Moment.js JavaScript date library to add comprehensive formatting to Moment Durations.

Using moment-duration-format you can use the [`format()`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#template) method for duration object. In your case, you can use `'mm:ss.SS'` tokens where `mm` stands for minutes, `ss` stands for seconds and `SS` stands for milliseconds.

Since you want output like `00:23.80` instead of `23.80`, yuo can use [`{ trim: false }`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#trim) option.

So to change the displayed values for th `y` axis, your callback could be like the following:

```
callback: function(tickValue, index, ticks) {
  if (!(index % parseInt(ticks.length / 5))) {
    return moment.duration(tickValue/100, 's').format('mm:ss.SS');
  }
}
```

---

**Update after the comment about date:** You can convert `2011-04-11` to `april 14, 2011` using moment [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

```
moment('2011-04-11').format('MMMM DD, YYYY');
```

You simply parse your input using [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) (since it matches known ISO 8601 formats) and then use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) using `MMMM` for month name, `DD` for day of the month and `YYYY` for the year.

---

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrJNqz) my updated codepen that has the same code of the following snippet:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: [
      moment("2009-04-11").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2009-05-16").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2009-10-10").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2009-11-28").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2010-02-14").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2010-03-13").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2010-04-17").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2010-12-18").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2011-01-29").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2011-03-12").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2011-03-27").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2011-05-15").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2011-10-08").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2011-11-27").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2011-12-17").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2012-03-10").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2012-05-13").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2012-10-07").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2012-11-03").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2012-11-10").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2013-05-11").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2013-10-12").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2013-11-09").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2014-01-11").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2014-11-07").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2014-11-15").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2015-03-07").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2015-04-12").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2015-11-14").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2016-11-12").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2016-12-11").format('MMMM DD, YYYY'),
      moment("2017-01-08").format('MMMM DD, YYYY')
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "time",
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        borderColor: "#0088d4",
        data: [
          15170,
          15026,
          15209,
          14335,
          14293,
          14725,
          14560,
          13511,
          13422,
          13230,
          13795,
          12830,
          13126,
          12988,
          12950,
          12750,
          12702,
          12395,
          12534,
          12276,
          12440,
          12462,
          12365,
          12465,
          12021,
          11976,
          12050,
          12016,
          11984,
          11972,
          11717,
          11995
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    elements: {
      line: {
        tension: 0
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 1,
            callback: function(tickValue, index, ticks) {
              if (!(index % parseInt(ticks.length / 5))) {
                return moment.duration(tickValue/100, 's').format('mm:ss.SS',{ trim: false });
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 970px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>times chart</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="auto" height="100"></canvas>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit more? Where would I need to place this callback function? And let's say, the time is 23 seconds and 80 hundredths of a second: in this case it would say "00:23.80" instead of 23.80, how would I do this? Also: I think this is a solution for the time, not the date?

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman sorry I posted the first verision of my answer from mobile app, just wanted to give a quick solution. I've updated my answer, I hope it's clearer now. Anyway, what is the issue with date? Sorry but I do not understand what you what to do with the date.

Comment: Yes, looks very clear to me. I think I still need to code my own formatter, since I do want it to look a bit different, but that will be fine I guess. Now, Moment.js does not have a method to conver the date from `2011-04-11` to `april 14, 2011`?? The only reason I did not mark my question answered is because I am still looking for a way to convert the date. But great work on the time conversion!

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman I've updated my answer including the conversion from `2011-04-11` to `april 14, 2011` (that it's quite easy using moment).

Comment: wow thanks! That is quite easy indeed. I just needed an example. Thank you!

Comment: @VincenczoC Maybe you also know a solution for the problem I encountered after this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965174/javascript-chart-js-tooltip-shows-wrong-x-axis-value