# Chart.js two y axes line chart tooltip value incorrect for 2nd y axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have created a working chart with chart.js and I would like to fix a minor problem I have noticed with it.

Have a look [at this pen.](https://codepen.io/Anseur/pen/KKwyPzV) or the copy below.

```js
// Global settings for all charts
// set default to not fill any lines
Chart.defaults.global.elements.line.fill = false;

// lines chart with 4 lines and time on x axis
var ChartData = {
  labels: ['08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00'],
  datasets: [{
    type: 'line',
    label: 'A',
    yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(110,250,150,0.3)",
    borderColor: "rgba(110,250,150,0.5)",
    data: [2500, 2600, 4100, 3400, 2150, 3560, 4500]
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    label: 'B',
    yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(50,255,90,0.3)",
    borderColor: "rgba(50,255,90,0.5)",
    data: [420, 510, 900, 700, 920, 950, 820]
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    label: 'Wait',
    yAxisID: "y-axis-2",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,000,000,0.3)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255,000,000,0.8)",
    data: ['00:28', '00:45', '00:15', '00:12', '00:22', '00:55', '00:10']
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    label: 'D',
    yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(120,180,255,0.3)",
    borderColor: "rgba(120,180,255,0.5)",
    data: [4200, 1100, 1300, 1850, 1780, 2440, 3800]
  }]
};


var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart");
// declare a chart
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: ChartData,
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart.js line Two Y Axis"
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'label'
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
          time: {
            parser: 'hh:mm:ss',
            unit: 'seconds',
            unitStepSize: 3600,
            min: '08:00:00',
            max: '14:00:00',
            displayFormats: {
              'seconds': 'HH:mm'
            }
          },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Time'
        },
          // makes time durations on x axis stay in linier time scale.
          distribution: 'linear',
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        id: "y-axis-1",
        position: "left",
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Other Title Here'
        }
      }, {
        id: "y-axis-2",
        position: "right",
          ticks: {
          max: '20:00',
          min: '00:00'
        },
        type: 'time',
          time: {
            parser: 'mm:ss',
            unit: 'seconds',
            unitStepSize: 3600,
            min: '08:00:00',
            max: '14:00:00',
            displayFormats: {
              'seconds': 'MM.ss'
            }
          },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Wait (mm:ss)',
          fontColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.8)'
        },
        type: 'time',
          time: {
            parser: 'mm:ss',
            unit: 'seconds',
            unitStepSize: 60,
            min: '00:00',
            max: '20:00',
            displayFormats: {
              'seconds': 'mm.ss'
            }
          },
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

If you move the pointer over the points on the red line data, you can see that the tooltip shows correct values for all other lines, but instead of the correct value for the red line, it displays the values of the time I have on the x axes. The actual chart line for the red value is in the correct place, only the value in the tooltip is wrong. In this example, the red line is the only line that uses the 2nd y axes on the right, so I assume it's something to do with that.

I did look at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965174/javascript-chart-js-tooltip-shows-wrong-x-axis-value) but my axes is already set up as time type, assuming I'm following that answer correctly.

How can I correct this?

Note: The x axes times are times in the day from 8AM to 2PM. The times on the 2nd y axes on the right are not times of the day, but lengths of time in minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the *X axis* of each of the **Wait** data.
Paste it like this in your code:

```
data: [
    { x: "08:00", y: "00:28" },
    { x: "09:00", y: "00:45" },
    { x: "10:00", y: "00:15" },
    { x: "11:00", y: "00:12" },
    { x: "12:00", y: "00:22" },
    { x: "13:00", y: "00:55" },
    { x: "14:00", y: "00:10" }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. To explain what I realised from Soul Eaters answer, is that when you have a 2nd y axis in chart.js, it seems like a single graph, but it basically behaves like two different graphs overlayed on top of each other. If you have the same number of data points, the way I did it in the question above will still line up, but chart.js does not know for sure which values in the 2nd y axis line up with which x values until you specify like in Soul's answer, which is why it was unable to display the values in the tooltip.